# How do I copy an image from the output in Jupyter Notebook 7+?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, copy-paste

I've been working with Jupyter Notebooks for quite a while. When working with visualisations, I like to copy the output image from a cell by right clicking the image and selecting "Copy Image" from the context menu:

[image]

I like working with the direct copy from the notebook, especially for answering questions on Stack Overflow, so I'd rather not store them to disk. That would be a real reason to revert to legacy notebooks for me.

However with the [Notebook 7 migration](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebook_7_features.html) coming, I gave the beta a try by running `pip install notebook --pre --upgrade` and to my surprise I can't right click, copy the output image because the new Jupyter context menu pops up instead.

[image]

This really breaks my workflow. How can I copy an image from the output of a cell in notebook 7+?

Comment: Assuming you're using matplotlib, then you can just save the plot to disk

Comment: Did you try holding down `Shift` while right-clicking to access the native menu, as spelled out [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2685#issuecomment-315382217)? For context, Version 7 of Jupyter Notebook is built off JupyterLAb components (see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/notebook-7-pre-releases-are-available/16063?u=fomightez)), and that means that some of the interface and GUI abilities you can learn by seeing how JupyterLab users handled them.

Comment: Oh yeah, that totally works @wayne.  I think with the coming change to notebook many will hit the same problem. Feel free to detail it in an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hold down `Shift` while right-clicking to access the native browser menu, as spelled out [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/2685#issuecomment-315382217).

For context, Version 7 of Jupyter Notebook is built off JupyterLab components (see [here](https://jupyter.org/enhancement-proposals/79-notebook-v7/notebook-v7.html) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/notebook-7-pre-releases-are-available/16063?u=fomightez)), and that means that some of the interface and GUI abilities you can learn by seeing how JupyterLab users handle them.

---

Tested by launching a temporary session via MyBinder from [here](https://gist.github.com/jtpio/0f3c67a6a1767360df0e79b52d74a5fe#file-readme-md) and works in Chrome on a Mac.