# Jupyter Notebook has no top menu "Cell"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Just installed freshly Jupyter and was surprised to find out that the "Cell" top menu is missing.

Is this a new "feature"?

How can I get that menu back?

I checked the options and the various other menus but I can't find a way to get that "Cell" top menu.

Also, I notice that under "Help" the option to customize the short-cuts is missing, too. How can I get this back, too?

[image]

Comment: Your post is basically a duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76836781/8508004) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/jupyter-notebook-menu-missing-options/20868?u=fomightez). The interface of Jupyter Notebook Version7 is different. See my coverage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004). If you prefer to continue with the older interface understanding that there will be a more limited forward development path, you should look into NbClassic.

Comment: As for editing the shortcuts, there's a Settings Editor under Settings, see [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html#Keyboard-Shortcut-Customization). To get to it, go to the Jupyter Dashboard where you choose to open a new notebook or terminal, etc.. You can get to the dashboard by clicking on the Jupyter logo in the upper left. From there you choose '`Settings`' from along the File menu and then '`Settings Editor`' at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For editing the shortcuts in Jupyter Notebook Version7 and forward, there's a Settings Editor under Settings, see [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html#Keyboard-Shortcut-Customization).

Presently, to get to the place to edit the shortcuts, go to the Jupyter Dashboard where you choose to open a new notebook or terminal, etc.. You can get to the dashboard by clicking on the Jupyter logo in the upper left. From there you choose '`Settings`' from along the File menu and then '`Settings Editor`' at the bottom.

---

The short answer to OP's first question about the main File menu ribbon being more streamlined and missing options seen in Notebook 6 and earlier is that it is indeed a 'feature'. I covered current options in the Jupyter landscape in [my comment (& references therein) above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76926554/jupyter-notebook-has-no-top-menu-cell/76929447#comment135616275_76926554).

---

###### Accessing former 'Cell' menu options

In comments raised after this answer was originally posted, using the former 'Cell' menu options was raised. In particular the option to clear out the cells.

Now in Jupyter Notebook Version7 and forward, you can still clear the output from all cells. There are at least two ways to trigger this:

- You can find it presently under the '`Edit`' selection along the File menu ribbon at the top: '`Edit`' > '`Clear Outputs of All Cells`'.
- Alternatively, you can right-click in any of the main notebook area. If you right-click in any of the gray area around the cells, that option appears right at the top. If you click in the white area of the main notebook pane, you'll see the option around the middle of the listed selections.

Similarly, you can restart the kernel under the current '`Kernel`' menu list that is listed on the File menu ribbon at the top, you you can find it listed whenever you right-click the main notebook pane area.

**You can assign Keyboard shortcuts for these if you want.** You can follow the 'JupyterLab-way' to do this as outlined [here for clearing all output cells](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60319284/8508004) and [for restarting the kernel & running all cells here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-save-a-lot-of-time-by-have-a-short-cut-to-restart-kernel-and-run-all-cells/11756/4?u=fomightez), as the tech underlying Notebook V7 and forward is built on top of the underlying JupyterLab components.

*Right-click addition is nice, what about the standard browser 'right-cick'-accessible abilities you previously accessed with '`right-click`' in the older notebook interface such as 'Save Image As...'?* Because Notebook Version 7 and forward is built on top of the JupyterLab components, the route is the same as in JupyterLab. Namely, hold down Shift while right-clicking to access the native browser menu, as spelled out in [my answer to 'How do I copy an image from the output in Jupyter Notebook 7+?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649945/8508004).

Comment: Thanks for the information! I used the Cell menu to clear the output of all cells. The only thing which comes to mind now is to re-start the kernel. Is there any other way?

Comment: I added a section on triggering what you raised in your last comment. Let me know if that covers the two items you raised in your last comment. I sort of didn't get the restart the kernel question you raised because that is still in the same location under 'Kernel', but it does also now appear in the options you can find in the list of options when you right-click, which wasn't an available route before.

Comment: For those looking to provide feedback on the keyboard shortcuts and issues with them, see [the GitHub issue 'Fix keyboard shortcut regressions in new Notebook interface'](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7041).