# Jupyter CellToolbar menu missing

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to follow [this tutorial](https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-presentation/) for converting my Jupyter notebook to slides but I get stuck. The first step in *Create Presentation* is to click `View`➡️`CellToolbar`➡️`Slideshow` however my `View` menu does not have a `CellToolbar` option

Expected
[image]

Actual
[image]

I cannot see anything in the tutorial, or others like it stating that I need a different package but something must be wrong.

Any suggestions for what could cause this?

Comment: That was already asked [here in a post titled 'Jupyter Notebook has no top menu "Cell"'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76926554/8508004). It boils down to you are using something more current then the tutorial you are following.  You have options to deal with this as posted in my answer there. The most direct would be to switch to using nbclassic so that your interface matches. By the way your link to the tutorial in your post doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Not the same Cell tool but the same root cause. Downgrading notebook to 6.5.5 solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information [Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8508004/wayne) shared in his comment lead me to the answer. Downgrading from Notebook 7.0.3 to 6.5.5 solved the issue.