# I'm having trouble copying from Jupyter notebooks using the mouse. What can I do?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, mouse, right-click

I can't copy from the jupyter-notebook by right-clicking the mouse and then clicking copy. I am able to use the keyboard to copy from the jupyter-notebook, but not with the mouse.

Thanks in advance.

I tried to copy with the mouse and it won't let me. It doubles my work rate.

Comment: Have you tried holding down `Shift` while right-clicking to access the native browser menu using your mouse? I believe that should get you at copy.  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76649945/8508004) that is a follow-up to [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76649888/how-do-i-copy-an-image-from-the-output-in-jupyter-notebook-7/76649945#comment135138724_76649888). If that doesn't help ... We need details. Your post doesn't clearly detail versions of Jupyter, the exact interface, or exactly what you are trying to copy, i.e., the entire cell vs. a specific selection.

Comment: Thank you!

I press shift, then when I right-click, if I don't right-click exactly at the beginning of the part I'm trying to copy, and instead click somewhere in the highlighted part I'm trying to copy, it cuts the text I'm trying to copy, and starts it at the position I mouse-clicked to press copy.

version - 7.0.6
it runs on port 8888 by default.

The entire view of the jupyter notebook has changed since I started my last project in it. I'm working with .ipynb files now, maybe that's related. I would be happy if I could return to the previous state.

Thank you!

Comment: There are ways to go to the previous state; however, as you seem relatively new to working with Jupyter (they've been actual `.ipynb` files with that extension for many years now) I'm going to encourage you not to do that. The current version you are using Notebook 7+, and the parallel tech JupyterLab, encompass the current direction of development of Jupyter, and thus adopting them now will let you develop your familiarity with the current ecosystem gradually rather than suddenly being forced somewhere down the road in a few years or so. That being said, you may though choose to hang on ...

Comment: <continued> with what was working better for you. In that case you seek NbClassic, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76837597/8508004) about the new interface, the current Jupyter ecosystem, and the option of installing and using NbClassic, which is the older style document-centric interface you seek. Another option would be perhaps trying Jupyter Notebooks inside VSCode. A lot of people seem to like that and maybe the process of copying text there is more amenable to your current working style.

Comment: As for you issue, I gather it is sort of solved, however, less than ideally at this point? If you felt it could be improved in some manner that is under the control of Jupyter and not the browser, you may wish to explore what others have said [among the issues here (there's a search bar)](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues) and add your input or open an entirely new issue, if warranted, where you describe specifically what is going on and how the older style was an enhancement for you.

Comment: Okay Wayne, I'll take your advice. I will stay with this version to learn it, and give feedback to Jupyter via the link you sent me. You helped me a lot, thanks!